# Why appcompat-v7:23.4.0 include 2 support v4？

Tags: android

I use `gradle app:dependencies` and I found that v7 include 2 v4 package，i want to  konw why ，and in this situlation how can i only keep one？

```
_releaseApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0 (*)
\--- project :app
     \--- project :small
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNEc4.jpg)

Comment: With the advancement in the Android studio. Developer's team have added a separate file to include the gradle version on which the material design and dependency of the project rely. You can also change it in case you want to use some-other functionality.

Comment: I just want to konw , why google pack two supportv4 in a v7 ,is this a mistake？

Comment: If two artifacts depend on a common artifact it is of course included just once in your project. It's just a dependency tree visualization not a physical archive.

Answer (score 0):

I got the wrong about the gradle,I think gradle will pack two support v4 when build a apk,but grale will remove useless package auto,this question is useless.